# Conversion of 2D image to 3D image

Tags: image, 3d, 2d

i am going to develope a system which will take a 2D still image as a input & 3D image as a output.
So the steps are:
1. creating a depth map from 2D image
2. creating 3D image from depth map and original image.
Can anybody suggest me the algorithms to generate the depth map of 2D image?

Comment: You might want to check out the algorithms used in Make3D: http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no 100% bullet proof algorithm that can convert a 2D image to a 3D model. Simply said, there's not enough information inside a 2D image to fully construct something 3D. Some 3D TV sets manage to do some fake 3D from the 2D input but nothing really convincing (and sometimes wrong.)

What famous softwares do (like the one in the Kinect), is use several sources instead of one single 2D image. With pictures from different angles, you can track some particular features in the images and with geometric computations output something 3D. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images for full explanation.

If you're stuck with a single image, the best known tool is the human eye... Humans can easily reconstruct 3D from a picture, by unconsciously merging several factors, such as their experience of the scene, the focus blur, "far-away fog effect", etc... So the best way for you to have a result, is to do the depth map yourself in any image editing software...

Julien